# how to use variable of method into main method

Tags: java, methods

I wanted to print final value of variable `count` but when i use this in `countTrees` method this will print intermediate values also. and i can't get access `count` in my main method. I don't want to change returning variable

```
public class treecount {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        countTrees(3);
        //System.out.println(countTrees(3));
        //System.out.println(count);
    }
    public static int countTrees(int numKeys) {
        //int temp = 0;
          int count = 0;
          if (numKeys <=1) {
              count += 1;
            return(1); 
          } 
          else { 
            int sum = 0; 

            int left, right, root;

            for (root=1; root<=numKeys; root++) { 
              left = countTrees(root-1); 
              right = countTrees(numKeys - root);

              // number of possible trees with this root == left*right 
              sum += left*right; 
              count += root*left*right;

            }
            System.out.println(count);
            return(sum); 
          }   
    } 

}
```

Output:

```
3
3
10
```

Output Required:

```
10
```

Hey guys help me with this problem thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way - a bit of a workaround, but it's a crazy recursive jungle there...

The boolean `internal` signals if the function has been called from inside or outside of itself, thus determines wether the calculation is complete in which case to return `count` to the outsde caller, instead of `sum` to itself.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
//        countTrees(3, false);
        System.out.println(countTrees(3, false));
        //System.out.println(count);
    }
    public static int countTrees(int numKeys, boolean internal) {
        //int temp = 0;
          int count = 0;
          if (numKeys <=1) {
              count += 1;
            return(1); 
          } 
          else { 
            int sum = 0; 

            int left, right, root;

            for (root=1; root<=numKeys; root++) {
              left = countTrees(root-1, true); 
              right = countTrees(numKeys - root, true);

              // number of possible trees with this root == left*right 
              sum += left*right; 
              count += root*left*right;

            }
//            System.out.println(count);
            if( internal )return(sum);
            else return count;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, try this:

Remove the System.out.println(count); from the count trees method (since this is why it's printing out multiple times.

In the main method, use the System.out.println(countTrees(3)); you commented out before.

Note: you are returning a **value**, not a *variable* in the countTrees method

Comment: no this will print value of variable sum which 5 in this case.what i want is print value of varable count